How to Add a Convex Function to a Nonconvex Function to Achieve Convexity
Assume that I have a nonconvex function $f(x)$ and I'm interested in finding a convex function $g(x)$ such that the sum $f(x) + g(x)$ is convex. One common approach I’ve seen is to add a term like $\frac{\alpha}{2} |x|^2$, which results in a weakly convex function if $\alpha \geq0 $ is chosen appropriately. However, I would like to learn about other functions $g(x)$ that can make the sum $f(x) + g(x)$ convex.
Are you guys familiar with such functions g(x)?
Thanks a lot!

It depends on what you want to do with $f+g$. For $f (x):= \sqrt{ |x|} $ no choice of a convex function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ makes $f+g$ convex.

Adding $\frac{\alpha}{2}x^2$ might not make it convex. E.g. if $f(x)=x^3$.

In order to do that you need several properties of $f$: It has to be continuous, have  one-sided derivative at all points, etc.

Hello guys
My main goal is to add a convex function and subtract a convex function from a nonconvex function so that I can apply the Difference of Convex (DC) optimization algorithm. Specifically, I want to achieve the following form: $(f(x) + g(x)) - g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is convex.
I don’t have any specific assumptions on $f(x)$, and I’d like to learn about as many suitable functions as possible that can fit this framework. Even functions that are only locally convex are of interest.

If $f$ is twice differentiable, then you can choose any convenient function which is $\ge |f''|$ everywhere and twice-integrate it (making any convenient choices for the constants of integration) to arrive at a suitable convex function $g$. If $f$ is not twice-differentiable everywhere, then as daw has demonstrated, it may not be possible. It depends on exactly why differentiation fails.
